# php Get users instagram photos and videos using Oauth without user authentication?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, instagram, feed

I want to show my users instagram feeds including photos and videos in my website, Is it possible to get these feeds without the user authentication?

Thanks n' regards,
John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it using the User's ID with the user media recent endpoint. This endpoint will return media for the user with ID 1234:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1234/media/recent
```

Comment: Try clicking the link - you get the error that the access_token is required. But access_token can only be obtained by user authorizing your app. The question remains, how to do this without an access_token?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  If the users account is private, then they will need to authenticate your application.  If public, you can use any access token to grab that users feed using the `users` endpoint.